# Github returns "Problems parsing JSON" when trying to create repo using curl

Tags: json, curl, github, github-api

I'm attempting to create a repo on github using curl. No matter how I attempt to format my JSON it always returns "Problems parsing JSON". Is there something I'm missing? Here is my statement:

```sh
curl --data '{"name":"newRepoName"}' -XPOST -u username:password http://giturl
```

Comment: I hand typed it and double checked that I had the right user path. Still Problems Parsing JSON.

Comment: I have this same problem. Just following the official [docs](https://developer.github.com/guides/getting-started/#repositories).

Answer (score 2):

Strange since it works for me. Are you using the correct GitHub API endpoint (/user/repos)?

```sh
curl --data '{"name":"testrepo"}' -X POST -u username https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including your token or password like this

```
  curl --data '{"name":"testrepo"}' \
       -X POST -u username:$TOKEN \
       https://api.github.com/user/repos
```